# Git Post-Receive Hook not being activated

Tags: git

I have a git repo on my EC2 Amazon Linux Development server. i am using SSH to push changes from my local git repo on my laptop.

i have confirmed that the push is working correctly as the contents of my local repo are mirrored on the Dev server. however it appears that my post-receive hook is not firing. as code is not getting checked out to my html directory.

i have even attempted putting an echo command to at least confirm that the hook was firing but there is no feedback in the command line except for on the local end the results of the push.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script for the "post-receive" event.
#
# The "post-receive" script is run after receive-pack has accepted a pack
# and the repository has been updated.  It is passed arguments in through
# stdin in the form
#  <oldrev> <newrev> <refname>
# For example:
#  aa453216d1b3e49e7f6f98441fa56946ddcd6a20 68f7abf4e6f922807889f52bc043ecd31b7$
#
# see contrib/hooks/ for a sample, or uncomment the next line and
# rename the file to "post-receive".

#. /usr/share/git-core/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html sudo git checkout -f
```

Comment: As a note: *sudo* is really a bad idea here. You should rather adjust the permissions in the work tree to let git-running user handle the checkout.

Comment: yeah that was throwing things at the wall seeing if it stuck.

Comment: I have the same problem just like yours. Have you solved it?

Comment: i did but i am not sure now what exactly it was that i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo` is likely not preserving the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable - it is quite often configured to provide a sanitized environment for the commands that it runs, especially when they run as `root`. `git` has some command line arguments (`--git-dir` and `--work-tree` specifically) that accomplish the same thing that the environment variable is intended to. You'll probably need to use those in this case.

Comment: i've tried another directory that i do not need to use SUDO, and i am getting the same result. im not even sure if the hook is firing as there is no output when i use the echo command.

Comment: Have you renamed the hook script, as suggested in the comment? That seems to obvious, but it's worth asking... Also, is the script set to executable?

Comment: i've removed the entire checkout command and replaced it with a simple echo statement, and i did set it as executable with chmod +x. -rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user  579 Aug 21 17:45 post-receive

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might help you with your cloud server problem, but I had to manually edit /etc/fstab file. My /srv/git folder was symlinked to a harddrive, which was mounted with the 'noexec,user' command via fstab file. Changing it to 'defaults' finally solved my problem. Took me 8 hours to figure it out.
You could also try

```
$cd /path/to/.git/hooks
$sudo chown git:git post-receive
```

for the post-receive file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Don't forget init repo with --shared option:

   $ git init --shared --bare repo/html.git

   $ sudo chgrp -R git repo/html.git

   $ sudo usermod -a -G git www-data
2. Add Git user to sudoers (allow nopass for www-data user):

   $ sudo visudo

   Defaults:git !authenticate

   git ALL=(www-data) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
3. Our one-line post-receive hook:

   sudo -u www-data git --git-dir=/home/git/repo/html.git/ --work-tree=/var/www/html checkout -f